# Update global Model from controllers in SAPUI5

Tags: model, controller, components, sapui5, updatemodel

Is possible update the global model of the project in SAPUI5 from one of my controllers? I have some views with their respective controllers and I need to update the global model from some of this controllers.

Is possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. The below code from your controller should give you reference to global model

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("modelName")
```

Comment: But if I do this... is like a copy right? I'm not updating the model for all the program right? The original model. Because I need that some information change in the original model for all the views, then I need to update the global model not the copy.

Comment: you will get the reference ... not a copy

Comment: Models are propagate. No need to go over the component

Comment: Correct. As long as they are not overridden. Say in manifest you declared a default model and in a controller of a view you set a default model. In this case, how would you access the model declared globally in manifest? And that's the question here.
```
// true if not overridden in the controller of the view, or else false
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel() === this.getView().getModel()
```

Comment: thats not in the question. Overriding component models with a local model is not considered as clean code/best practice

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. 